# Mutliple if else statements to a meaningful data structure

Tags: java, data-structures, control-structure

There are plenty of **nested if else statements** in the legacy code (**VB Script**) which I want to migrate to a meaningful representation for easier maintenance in a **Java** application. Most of these statements are used to generate a sql statement based on user selection of parameters. Any suggestions to better model this logical branching problem as a data structure viz., directed **graphs**?

For example, if the parameters are:

age
department
grade

```
String finalSQL = “”;
if(department is not ‘HR’){
   // append something to finalSQL
if (age between 21-35)
{
  // append something to finalSQL
}
else if (age between 35-40)
{
// append something to finalSQL
}else{
// append something to finalSQL
}
} else {

if(grade > g7){
// append something to finalSQL
}else if (grade is g2 or g4 or g6){
// append something to finalSQL
} else{
// append something to finalSQL
}

}

return finalSQL;
```

Comment: Can you please show some pseudo code? The easiest way to avoid `if-else` statements is to take advantage of `polymorphism`

Comment: share some code please

Comment: Could you give a more concrete example? There are some ways to avoid `if-else` chains (e.g. the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)), but which one(s) to use depends on the exact problem.

Comment: Could you give the details like is there any nested if or it is simply if -elseif ....?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469195/how-to-refactor-code-to-avoid-multiple-if-s-from-interview/29476152#29476152

Comment: These if else statements are running for pages chunking some part of a bigger SQL. For better readability I have taken all the chunks of the SQL to a separate properties file. But then still I have to write all the if else statements which are present in the legacy code :(

Answer (score -1):

One alternative of multiple if else statement where these conditions represents a specific state , then i usually go for [State Design Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state) or [command Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199646/long-list-of-if-statements-in-java) if they are simple commands

Think of vending mention where depending on state of machine like empty/non empty/no of coins, you have specific behaviour

Another readable way is switch- case statement but thats mainly makes it more readable

See this [Converting many 'if else' statements to a cleaner approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136721/converting-many-if-else-statements-to-a-cleaner-approach)

Comment: *Another readable way is switch- case statement but thats mainly makes it more readable* -> this is not true. For primitives, `switch-case` is more performant. One way or the other, `switch-case` does not solve OP's problem.

Comment: My problem is that there are several complex combinations of input parameter values for which different string chunks are added to the final sql string.

Comment: i don't understand negative voting without reason . Seriously negative vote without reason should be banned