# Use Switch for element instead of if/elseif

Tags: java, webdriver

```
public void profileSection(String displayName, String fName, String lName, String Address_1,) throws Exception
{
    myAccountPageNative(CONSTANTs.MY_ACCOUNT_LINK);
    clickLink(CONSTANTs.MY_PROFILE_SECTION);        

    if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.DISPLAY_NAME_TXTBOX)).isDisplayed())
    {
        log.step("Optional..... BUT you will need it when Commenting on any article....");
        elementPresent_Click(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.DISPLAY_NAME_TXTBOX), displayName);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }else if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.MYACCT_EMAIL_TXTBOX)).isDisplayed())
    {
        log.step("Check if Email txtbox is enabled or not...... pls wait.");
        txtBoxDisabled(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.MYACCT_EMAIL_TXTBOX),null);
        Thread.sleep(2000); 
        log.step("Text box is disabled..... move to next step");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }else if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.FIRST_NAME)).isDisplayed())
    {
        log.step("Input First Name......");
        txtBoxDisabled(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.FIRST_NAME),fName);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }else if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.LAST_NAME)).isDisplayed())
    {
        log.step("Input Last Name......");
        txtBoxDisabled(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.LAST_NAME),lName);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }else if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.ADDRESS_1)).isDisplayed())
    {
        log.step("Input Address 1......");
        txtBoxDisabled(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.ADDRESS_1),Address_1);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
        log.step("Click Save Changes Button......");
        txtBoxDisabled(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.SAVE_CHANGES_BTN),null);            
    }
```

> Please am trying to use a switch instead of too many if statements. just to make my code more readable. Since switch evaluates a single variable, Can i use switch with my code cos it looks a bit more complex i guess.
>   An suggestion please, as all have different element to be selected using css Selector.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is it the case that only one of those elements will have `isDisplayed() == true` at any time? Is it guaranteed that exactly one will be true at all times?

Comment: Take a look at this stackoverflow post: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049094/replacing-if-else-statement-with-pattern

Comment: @Erick ...No, all will be true always as am validating the text box first before .sendKeys(). So if the text box/button is displayed, then sendKey. The code works fine but just want to know if i can use switch since am verifying different elements at different stage. Its an Account page with all the text box displayed. The text boxes are optional but just validating for testing purpose.

Comment: Then I really don't understand. You're doing an `if/else-if/else` on conditions that will all be true always? One of us is confused.

Comment: @mnille Good reference, but how would you apply it here?

Comment: @Erick ..... I just thought of it now... You re right. I should only check the disabled text box. Since other text boxes will always be true, then i don't need an if statements then, just .sendKeys() will do......  Since the text boxes are optional, then they need not validated. ......Thanks for the light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misconception here (which are totally understandable for a new programmer).

You seem to think that using a switch over if/else will make your code more readable, truth is it most likely will not. So how do you make your code more readable? Simple, get rid of all your repetition.

For example, you call an `Thread.sleep` in every if/else. Instead pull it out and place it after your if/else statements.

Another thing you can do is you can move your find elements into their own variables at the top of your class. And then simply call the `isDisplayed` on them

Example:

```
displayNameTextbox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.DISPLAY_NAME_TXTBOX));
if(displayNameTextbox.isDisplayed())
{
    log.step("Optional..... BUT you will need it when Commenting on any article....");
    elementPresent_Click(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.DISPLAY_NAME_TXTBOX), displayName);

}
```

Since this seems to be in Selenium, I would actually recommend createing a Page Object and using that instead to simplify your code.

Another thing to note is you could separate each of those ifs into their own methods and simply check those when necessary as oppose to checking them all at once. But thats depends more on how you plan to use this.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be a more suitable and elegant solution.  Build an array of the elements you want to check and loop through these.

```
public void profileSection(String displayName, String fName, String lName, String Address_1, 
        String Address_2, String city, String country, 
        String postcode, String telephone) throws Exception
{
    myAccountPageNative(CONSTANTs.MY_ACCOUNT_LINK);
    clickLink(CONSTANTs.MY_PROFILE_SECTION);

    String [] elementNames = new String [] {
            CONSTANTs.DISPLAY_NAME_TXTBOX,
            CONSTANTs.MYACCT_EMAIL_TXTBOX,
            CONSTANTs.FIRST_NAME,
            CONSTANTs.LAST_NAME,
            CONSTANTs.ADDRESS_1
    };

    for (String elementName : elementNames) {
        if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(elementName)).isDisplayed()) {
            elementPresent_Click(By.cssSelector(elementName), displayName);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            break; // when found break out of loop
        }
    }

    log.step("Click Save Changes Button......");
    txtBoxDisabled(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.SAVE_CHANGES_BTN),null);            
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer.... Erick G. Hagstrom was also right as i never thought of it.... Its either i remove all the if/elseif and validate only the text box needed or perhaps, use your code. Both works well and good. Thanks once again guys. Getting more help and strength in this forum.... Makes my job a lot easier, as i do get answers to my confused solutions..... Thanks.

Comment: Just going through your sample code. If i get you right, does that mean i going to have more than one if statement since am sending different keys to different element?. The method takes in 4 parameters(String displayName, String fName, String lName, String Address_1)

Comment: You will have an if statement for each of the elementNames until you get one that has isDisplayed() then it breaks out of the loop.

Comment: Guess as much... Thanks a mill :)

Answer (score 0):

You already got the answer but I still give it a try. I will use `enum` to remove `if/else` and the code will be more object oriented. Btw - apart from if/else there are many other areas where code can be improved e.g. naming conventions.

> MyTest class

```
public class MyTest {

    public void profileSection(String displayName, String fName, String lName,
            String Address_1, String Address_2, String city, String country,
            String postcode, String telephone) throws Exception {
        myAccountPageNative(CONSTANTs.MY_ACCOUNT_LINK);
        clickLink(CONSTANTs.MY_PROFILE_SECTION);

        Driver driver = null;
        MyEnum.test(driver, displayName, fName, lName, Address_1, Address_2, city, country, postcode, telephone);
        MyEnum.SAVE_CHANGES_BTN.doOperation(displayName, fName, lName, Address_1, Address_2, city, country, postcode, telephone);

    }

    private void clickLink(String myProfileSection) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private void myAccountPageNative(String myAccountLink) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

> MyEnum class

```
public enum MyEnum {

    DISPLAY_NAME_TXTBOX {
        @Override
        public void doOperation(String displayName, String fName, String lName,
                String Address_1, String Address_2, String city, String country,
                String postcode, String telephone) {
            elementPresent_Click(By.cssSelector(name()),
                    displayName);
        }

        private void elementPresent_Click(Selector cssSelector,
                String displayName) {

        }
    },
    MYACCT_EMAIL_TXTBOX {
        @Override
        public void doOperation(String displayName, String fName, String lName,
                String Address_1, String Address_2, String city, String country,
                String postcode, String telephone) {
            txtBoxDisabled(By.cssSelector(name()), null);
        }

        private void txtBoxDisabled(Selector cssSelector, Object object) {

        }
    },
    FIRST_NAME {
        @Override
        public void doOperation(String displayName, String fName, String lName,
                String Address_1, String Address_2, String city, String country,
                String postcode, String telephone) {
            txtBoxDisabled(By.cssSelector(name()), fName);
        }

        private void txtBoxDisabled(Selector cssSelector, Object object) {

        }
    },
    LAST_NAME {
        @Override
        public void doOperation(String displayName, String fName, String lName,
                String Address_1, String Address_2, String city, String country,
                String postcode, String telephone) {
            txtBoxDisabled(By.cssSelector(name()), lName);
        }

        private void txtBoxDisabled(Selector cssSelector, Object object) {
        }
    },
    ADDRESS_1 {
        @Override
        public void doOperation(String displayName, String fName, String lName,
                String Address_1, String Address_2, String city, String country,
                String postcode, String telephone) {
            txtBoxDisabled(By.cssSelector(name()), Address_1);
        }

        private void txtBoxDisabled(Selector cssSelector, Object object) {
        }
    },
    SAVE_CHANGES_BTN {
        @Override
        public void doOperation(String displayName, String fName, String lName,
                String Address_1, String Address_2, String city, String country,
                String postcode, String telephone) {
        }
    };


    public static void test(Driver driver, String displayName, String fName, String lName,
            String Address_1, String Address_2, String city, String country,
            String postcode, String telephone) {
        for(MyEnum enum1 : MyEnum.values()) {
            if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(enum1.name())).isDisplayed()) {
                enum1.doOperation(displayName, fName, lName, Address_1, Address_2, city, country, postcode, telephone);
            }
        }
    }

    abstract public void doOperation( String displayName, String fName, String lName,
            String Address_1, String Address_2, String city, String country,
            String postcode, String telephone);
}
```