# Need approach for Setting value to a property based on numerous conditions

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have many properties spread across a number of classes. Values to these properties need to be assigned based on a number of conditions (around 5 to 8 for each property). I am looking for an alternative for numerous 'if else' conditions.

I have come across 'Rule Engine' off late but AFAIK it can be used for *validating* the rules.

Any design suggestion would be of great help.

Comment: Seems to be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049094/replacing-if-else-statement-with-pattern

Comment: @Rahul Please post some of your code.

Comment: @andreasnico But that is Java. There can be a more elegant solution if you use C#

Comment: If you didn't understand my answer, I updated it to include an example, see if it helps you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is a "better" solution *for you*, but I'll try to explain.

> Value to these properties need to be assigned based on a number of conditions (around 5 to 8 for each property).

I think you mean that you always need to write this, which is annoying:

```
if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3 && condition4 && condition5) {
    Property1 = Value1;
}

if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3 && condition4 && condition5) {
    Property2 = Value2;
}
// ...
```

I think maybe this method can solve your problem?

```
public static void SetValueForPropertyIf<T>(Predicate<object>[] conditions, ref T property, T value) {
    foreach (var predicate in conditions) {
        if (!predicate(null)) {
            return;
        }
    }
    property = value;
}
```

And you can just call the method with a list of lambda expressions, ignore the argument (because it's always null), a variable to be passed by reference, and a value to set if all the conditions are met.

However, this only works for variables because I'm pretty sure properties cannot be passed by reference (with the `ref` keyword). So you have to declare your properties like this:

```
private int someVariable;

public int SomeVariable {
    get {return someVariable;}
    set {someVariable = value;}
}
```

And if you don't like the parameter of the `Predicate` delegate not being used, define your own delegate!

```
public delegate bool MyDelegate();
```

Here is an example of how to use this method, in case you didn't understand what I meant.

```
class MyClass {
    private int someVariable;

    public int SomeVariable {
        get {return someVariable;}
        set {someVariable = value;}
    }

    public MyClass() {
        someVariable = 10;
        MyDelegate[] conditions = {
            (() => 7 < 10),
            (() => 77 == 77),
            (() => "Sweeper is awesome".Contains("Sweeper")),
            (() => String.IsNullOrEmpty(""))
        };
        SetValueForPropertyIf(conditions, ref someVariable, 20);
    }
}
```

In this class's constructor, I first created some conditions, which are all true. Then I call the method with these conditions. Note that I used `someVariable` (The field) instead of `SomeVariable` (The property) as the `ref` parameter.

And then you can print `SomeVariable`:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
Console.WriteLine(mc.SomeVariable);
```

The output is 20. Hooray!