# Replace Multiple If\Else with Design Pattern

Tags: java, if-statement, design-patterns, conditional-statements

Based on various threads on SO (ex. [Replacing if else statement with pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049094/replacing-if-else-statement-with-pattern) ) I understand that I can replace multiple if\else statements with the `Command` pattern.

My situation is a bit different.

I have a series of `Commands` and I need to execute each `Command` only if the previous command was unsuccessful.

For example, suppose I need to retrieve text from a hypothetical web page - I could scrape the text directly from the page using screen scraping or I could fetch the text from the API. I would only want to fetch the text from API if screen scraping was not successful. In other words I would only execute the "fetch" command if the "scrape" command didn't work.

In this case, I  would test if the scraped String is empty or equal to null and then execute the second Command. If the second command is also unsuccessful I would execute the third Command and so on.

The important point is that we only execute subsequent commands if a certain condition is true/false. The condition is always the same for each Command but the number of commands might grow in the future.

I cannot implement this via the typically suggested route (using a `Map` and `Command` interface) bec this would not execute the next `Command` if the first one failed (it would also be unable to check if a `Command` was successful or not)

What design pattern could be used to solve this problem?

Comment: If the condition is inherent to the command: Run the command, make it return `true` for success. Put all commands in a list, run all commands in that list until the first one succeeds. Unfortunately, Java Stream don't have `takeWhile()`.

Comment: I think you are looking for the [chain of responsibility pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, use the [Chain of Responsibility](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073684/java-web-development/follow-the-chain-of-responsibility.html) Pattern which can keep trying different implementations in serial until one succeeds.

Let's say your Command has this interface where a handled Request returns a `Result` object if it succeeds or `null` if it failed ( could also use a boolean or `Optional` or whatever you want)

```
public interface Command{

  Result handle( Request request);
}
```

Then your chained Command could wrap several other Commands and try each one until something works.

```
public class ChainedCommand implements Command {
    //could also be set in a constructor instead
    List<Command> commandChain = Arrays.asList( new ScrapperCommand(),
                                            new ApiCommand());


    public Result handle( Request request){

         Result result = null;
         Iterator<Command> iter = commandChain.iterator();
         while( result ==null && iter.hasNext()){
              result = iter.next().handle(request);
         }

         return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

People have suggested using the `chain of responsibility` pattern however as I was thinking of the problem it occurred to me I could use a variation of the `Command` pattern to solve this problem. It works like this.

Replace each `if` statement with a corresponding class which implements the `Command` interface. In our example, I would implement the classes `ScreenScrapeTextCommand` and `FetchTextFromAPICommand`. Since each class will implement the `Command` interface we will add the method `execute()` to each class (this method will actually execute the functionality we need such as screen scraping or fetching from API).

We'd then create a new class which contains all related commands. Let's call this class `GetTextCommandCenter`. The class would contain a `list` of `Commands` in the form of `public List<Command> commandList;` We'd then hard code commands by adding the first two classes to the list in the following manner:

```
commandList.add(new ScreenScrapeTextCommand();
commandList.add(new FetchTextFromAPICommand();
```

We could then replace the `if\else` chain with the following:

```
public String replaceIfElseWithCommand()..

String text = null;
int commandIndex = 0;

while (text == null && text == someCondition)
{

text = new GetTextCommandCenter().commandList(commandIndex).execute();
commandIndex++;
}

return text;

}
```

As soon as a command is successful the the condition in the while loop will fail and method will return accordingly.

This way, we can easily add more Commands by adding more classes to `CommandCenter` class or change the precedence of individual commands quickly.

I think this is a simple and straightforward solution to my problem (but please place a comment if you think the `chain of responsibility` pattern is more suitable and why you think so)