# Replacing if else statement with pattern example

Tags: java, android

Based on various threads on SO (ex. [Replace Multiple If\Else with Design Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102499/replace-multiple-if-else-with-design-pattern) or [Replacing if else statement with pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049094/replacing-if-else-statement-with-pattern) ) I understand that I can replace multiple `if\else statements` with the `Command pattern`.

but the answers are far from simples or detailed for someone at my level ..i'll Have 60 `else if` blocks ..and mading some research i found out that the command pattern is best ..searching for tutorials on how to that step by step seemed hard, because all i found was expalined in complexed matters ..Believe me i won't put a question here if i didn't make a lot of resaearch and give up on internet! ( I believe the answers for this questions, will be appreciated by people trying to achieve the same thing, because there isn't obvious and well structured answers on internet so far)

**EDIT2:**


This is the structure of all my else if block:

```
 else if (data.equals("Exercice Inolerance, ")) {
        AddCode(mmDatabase.getTesta2());}

 else if (data.equals("Neta, ")) {
        AddCode(mmDatabase.getTesta3());}
```

PS: the itemList.add Could range from 1 to 10!

How to transform this into a command pattern by steps ..and Thanks!

Item.Java

```
public class Item {

    private String name = "";

    public Item() {
    }

    public Item(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setItemName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: You probably wouldn't.  You're thinking of patterns in the wrong way.  The point of a pattern is not to use it every time its remotely possible.  Its to be able to recognize methods of design and use them where applicable, and to describe your design to other people.  In this case there's be little to no point in using a Command pattern-  it would add little to no clarity to the code.

Comment: @Gabe Okey thanks ..and is there another way to simplify my code or i should do it manually ( add everytime the bloc under else if and changed it?)

Comment: You can break the individual ifs into their own functions.  That will improve clarity if the code gets large.  I don't really see an improvement in readability or maintainability by throwing in a bunch of overhead for a command pattern if its a relatively small set of static options.  Now if we were talking about a variable list of options registered at runtime, that would be a different answer.

Comment: If most of the custom code for each branch is about setting up parameters for the intent, consider static createIntent functions on each of the new activities.  That has a few benefits, including keeping all of the logic of creating an Activity's intents in the actual class (like parameter names).

Comment: @Gabe Sechan Thanks a lot for the answer ..but it Seems Hard ..Applying what you say, i'm new to android and this is my first app that i'm working on ..i don't mind do the stuff manually and i think i can handle changing every bloc ..but is it okey? is it acceptable to do that ? this what i'm worrying about ..if i'm doing something stupid by creating 60 else if bloc and changing them manually ..so again is it okey if i do them manually? Thanks again

Comment: You need to get the type of the item within the list rather than rely on the position for this to work the way you want

Answer (score 2):

first thing that comes to mind is to add a

```
Class<? extends Activity> handlerActivity;
```

field to the Item class, initialize it in constructor like

```
new Item("Jenny",Figures.class);
```

and in your onItemClick method just do

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DecisionTree.this, itemList.get(position).getHandlerActivity());
startActivity(i);
```

(or map Item to it's handling activity in any other way)

**as the first comment to your post says, don't apply patterns just for the sake of applying patterns. Of course the solution I provided here is far from perfect, it's just to help you get rid of the ifs. I assume Jenny, Bladna and Drafat are some kind of business constants so normally you'd use enum constants or separate classes (if your design is more complex) to achieve a polymorphic behavior**

**edit: here's your code**

```
public class Item {

    private final String name;
    private final Class<? extends Activity> handlingActivity;

    public Item(String name, Class<? extends Activity> handlingActivity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.handlingActivity = handlingActivity;
    }

    public Class<? extends Activity> getHandlingActivity() {
        return handlingActivity;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
itemList.add(new Item("Jenny", Figures.class));
            itemList.add(new Item("Bladna", State.class));
            itemList.add(new Item("Drafat", Casa.class));
            itemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(DecisionTree.this, itemList.get(position).getHandlingActivity())
                            startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
```

Comment: so if i understand your suggestion , 1/ i should add: `Class<? extends Activity> handlerActivity`;after onCreate in the same activity i'm working on..2/ and under i should add all items with the intent class: `new Item("Jenny",Figures.class)`; ..3/ do my normal stuff with if else bloc but instead of using on `listview.itemclicklistener( position ==0 do that, position ==1 do this )`..i should only add : `Intent intent = new Intent(DecisionTree.this, itemList.get(position).getHandlerActivity();
startActivity(i);`

Comment: is this right? This would be great also ..it'll reduce my code a lot!

Comment: @Zouhair add the Class<?...> field to the Item class, did you understand that correctly?

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm new to android and this is the first timeseeing this kind of code ..i've added the `item.class` in my post ..could you please update your post using my Item.class and specify where to add the rest of the code ..sorry for the trouble and thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: I saw your edit ..i'm really interested in your method because it'll reduce the code i'll be writing ..i wont no longer has to specifiy the intent for each position ..which is Good for me ..so could you make your answer more explicit using my item.class and specifiy where to put the other code ..Thanks

Comment: @Zou If each Activity is going to be receiving extras through the Intent, you'll still have to define if/else statements to determine what data goes into each Intent based on the class type

Comment: @cricket_007 or map the intent params in a similar way?

Comment: Adding `Map<String, Object>`, in order to be generic, sure, or a `Bundle` directly

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit! if i understand right .. I Have only one activity where i need to this kind of stuff .. and every time a list is diplayed, each item on click will lead to another activity! ..do you mean to specify: `DecisionTree.this` if i used this on different activity?

Comment: PS: i have tried the code ..and it works great ..i know it'll reduce only part of the code but since i can't reduce the entire code , it's fine for me ..but as i asked before is it not bad to have a lot of if/else statements? i don't mind adding them .and i can handle the changes to the body for else if ..but is it okey? not bad for the code ? if i wanted to do it manually? thanks a lot again for the help guys!

Comment: A few if/switch statements are fine when selecting a a strategy or for one time decisions, most of the times they can and should be avoided and can easily be replaced with polymorphic behavior, otherwise they tend to grow into multilevel nested ifs and you write code you'll never want to come back to. Feel free to accept my answer if it proved useful. Your post will most likely be removed though

Comment: But in my case how can i replaced it using "polymorphic behavior" ..and do you think is possible? ..if it is possible could you give me just the steps and i'll search on internet how to apply them so i won't bother your more ..thanks again!

Comment: @Nick Please see the updated list..i was able to turn the bloc of each else if into one line only ..do you think now is good to add a pattern and how ..Thanks Again!

Comment: your code is bad and you should feel bad about it. data.equals("Exercice Inolerance, ") - never do that. define your business objects as enum constants and save all those values as fields to have them defined at compile time, not assigned through decisions at runtime. stop trying to apply any pattern just for the sake of applying a pattern.