# How to restart a java program

Tags: java, switch-statement, application-restart

I'm very new to java and just playing around with the basics. I have made some kind of calculator.  ( there are probably easier calculators, just worked with what came to my mind )

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        double second;

        System.out.println("Please tell me a number");

        double first = input.nextDouble();
        input.nextLine(); // Consume newline left-over

        System.out.println("You chose the number " + first);

        System.out
                .println("Now please choose what you want to do with the number. ( divide, add, multiply or subtract )");
        String text = input.nextLine();

        switch (text) {
        case "divide":
            System.out.println("What do you want to divide your number " + first + " with?");
            second = input.nextDouble();
            double resultDivide = first / second;
            System.out.println(first + " / " + second + " = " + resultDivide);
            break;
        case "add":
            System.out.println("What do you want to add to your number " + first + "?");
            second = input.nextDouble();
            double resultAdd = first + second;
            System.out.println(first + " + " + second + " = " + resultAdd);
            break;
        case "multiply":
            System.out.println("What do you want to multiply your number " + first + " with?");
            second = input.nextDouble();
            double resultMultiply = first * second;
            System.out.println(first + " * " + second + " = " + resultMultiply);
            break;
        case "subtract":
            System.out.println("What do you want to subtract your number " + first + " with?");
            second = input.nextDouble();
            double resultSubtract = first - second;
            System.out.println(first + " - " + second + " = " + resultSubtract);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Sorry, I did not quite understand that. Please try again.");

        }

    }
```

So my question is: When it reaches default in the switch case statement, can I make the program restart from begginning?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: break and continue optionally takes an argument.

Comment: You could put a `while`- or a `do...while`-loop around the main part of the code.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: did a do while loop around the code, worked gr8, thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like all you want to do is loop until the user has specified a valid operation. In that case, you could use a while loop, watching a variable:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double second;
        System.out.println("Please tell me a number");
        double first = input.nextDouble();
        input.nextLine(); // Consume newline left-over

        System.out.println("You chose the number " + first);

        System.out
                .println("Now please choose what you want to do with the number. ( divide, add, multiply or subtract )");
        String text = input.nextLine();

        boolean correctOperation = true;

        do {
            correctOperation = true;

            switch (text) {
                case "divide":
                    System.out.println("What do you want to divide your number " + first + " with?");
                    second = input.nextDouble();
                    double resultDivide = first / second;
                    System.out.println(first + " / " + second + " = " + resultDivide);
                    break;
                case "add":
                    System.out.println("What do you want to add to your number " + first + "?");
                    second = input.nextDouble();
                    double resultAdd = first + second;
                    System.out.println(first + " + " + second + " = " + resultAdd);
                    break;
                case "multiply":
                    System.out.println("What do you want to multiply your number " + first + " with?");
                    second = input.nextDouble();
                    double resultMultiply = first * second;
                    System.out.println(first + " * " + second + " = " + resultMultiply);
                    break;
                case "subtract":
                    System.out.println("What do you want to subtract your number " + first + " with?");
                    second = input.nextDouble();
                    double resultSubtract = first - second;
                    System.out.println(first + " - " + second + " = " + resultSubtract);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Sorry, I did not quite understand that. Please try again.");
                    correctOperation = false;
                    text = input.nextLine();
            }
        } while(!correctOperation)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `while` loop is what you need. The enter condition of the loop will be the `default` case. Inside the loop you have to put this piece of code you used before:

```
System.out.println("Now please choose what you want to do with the number. ( divide, add, multiply or subtract )");
        String text = input.nextLine();
```

So it will continue to ask for the input until you don't get a `default` case.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need a while loop,e.g:

```
String text = input.readLine();
while(text != null) {
   switch(...)
}
```

And more, i want to give you some suggestions:

- you should check the "text" string you input if is null, if the "text" string is null, you will encounter the NullPointerException.
- if you will use so many case statements, you must consider the design patten, the link is [Replacing if else statement with pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049094/replacing-if-else-statement-with-pattern).