# Replace elseif with a more generic way

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I have this piece of code:

```
@Override
public void inform(String data) {
    if (data.equals(C.SubscriptionEvents.WINDOW_CLOSED)) {
        File tempFolder = new File("temp");
        File[] files = tempFolder.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File f : files) f.delete();
        }
    } else if (data.equals(C.Controller.Commands.SELECT_MODE_VERTICES)) {
        MainModel.setCurrentMode(Mode.VERTICES);
        display.getInfoSection().repaint();
    } else if (data.equals(C.Controller.Commands.SELECT_MODE_LINES)) {
        MainModel.setCurrentMode(Mode.LINES);
        display.getInfoSection().repaint();
    } else if (data.equals(C.Controller.Commands.SELECT_MODE_SECTORS)) {
        MainModel.setCurrentMode(Mode.SECTORS);
        display.getInfoSection().repaint();
    }
}
```

The method gets a string which is a Command name. According to the name, it does a specified behavior. As you can see, it starts to have too much elseifs (and probably will have more). This method belongs to an interface which is shared between packages so I decided to make the parameter as string.
Is there a better way to do it to avoid the method to be huge when there will be lots of commands (this includes switch case too)?

Comment: how about switch-case ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention switch case too - I mean't a way which won't make the function huge when it'll reach a point with lots of commands

Comment: You could model your commands as a separate class sharing a common interface, and put the behavior into that class implementations. This is the "command pattern" recommended by Ivan's answer.

Comment: Maybe this question can provide a solution: [Replacing if else statement with pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049094/replacing-if-else-statement-with-pattern)

Comment: Also: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: use hashmap ...just simply put key as "MODE" and value as Mode.xyz and on basis of key...you can set method argument

Comment: @dnault Your link misses a question. It links _codereview_ itself.

Comment: @LuCio Sorry for the confusion. I did not intend to link to a question. Just wanted to raise awareness of the *codereview* site, which is arguably a more appropriate venue for this question.

Comment: @dnault Yes, now I got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check `Command` pattern https://www.baeldung.com/java-command-pattern but it may require quite extensive refactoring and make method `inform()` accept objects of type `Command`

Comment: One could limit the extent of the refactoring by making the Command instances part of an inner class (even an Enum) and putting them in a Map<String,Command> structure. Then the signature of the inform mathod doesn't need to change.

Comment: How can I use this if my view is the one who invokes the call, but is in a different package (or even jar)? All the view knows is the name of the command(or even an enum is good for each command). The controller receives this command request with the name and is supposed to know which Command to instantiate according to the given name - how can the controller know that without a long elseif/switch?

Comment: @GadWissberg your controller will just do `invoke(Command c) { c.execute();}` and `Command` objects will be created in other places

Comment: Yes but I can't seem to understand where will the method object itself is instantiated? The view says "save file" (which is just a string or a shared enum value) and the controller receives that value and supposed to understand according to that which implementation of the Command interface to instantiate (which is the problematic part because of the elseif process)

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to understand it - this pattern fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

What about to use `Enum` instead of `if...else`?:

```
enum Event {
    NULL(null, context -> { }),
    WINDOWS_CLOSE(C.SubscriptionEvents.WINDOW_CLOSED, context -> {
        File tempFolder = new File("temp");
        File[] files = tempFolder.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File f : files) f.delete();
        }
    }),
    SELECT_MODE_VERTICES(C.Controller.Commands.SELECT_MODE_VERTICES, context -> {
        MainModel.setCurrentMode(Mode.VERTICES);
        display.getInfoSection().repaint();
    }),
    SELECT_MODE_LINES(C.Controller.Commands.SELECT_MODE_VERTICES, context -> {
        MainModel.setCurrentMode(Mode.LINES);
        display.getInfoSection().repaint();
    }),
    SELECT_MODE_SECTORS(C.Controller.Commands.SELECT_MODE_SECTORS, context -> {
        MainModel.setCurrentMode(Mode.SECTORS);
        display.getInfoSection().repaint();
    });

    private final String id;
    private final Consumer<Foo> consumer;

    Event(String id, Consumer<Foo> consumer) {
        this.id = id;
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    public final void accept(Foo context) {
        consumer.accept(context);
    }

    public static Event selectEvent(String data) {
        for (Event event : values())
            if (event.id.equals(data))
                return event;
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

And your code will be look like this one:

```
Event.selectEvent(data).accept(this);
```

Comment: You posted while I was writing my response.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an enum class, as follows:

```
public enum Command {
    WINDOW_CLOSED { //C.SubscriptionEvents.WINDOW_CLOSED
        public void invoke() {
            File tempFolder = new File("temp");
            File[] files = tempFolder.listFiles();
            if (files != null) {
                for (File f : files) f.delete();
            }
        }
    }
    ,SELECT_MODE_VERTICES { // C.Controller.Commands.SELECT_MODE_VERTICES
        public void invoke() {
            MainModel.setCurrentMode(Mode.VERTICES);
            display.getInfoSection().repaint();
        }
    }
    ,SELECT_MODE_LINES { // C.Controller.Commands.SELECT_MODE_LINES
        public void invoke() {
            MainModel.setCurrentMode(Mode.LINES);
            display.getInfoSection().repaint();
        }
    }
    ,SELECT_MODE_SECTORS { // C.Controller.Commands.SELECT_MODE_SECTORS
        public void invoke() {
            MainModel.setCurrentMode(Mode.SECTORS);
            display.getInfoSection().repaint();
        }
    }
    ;
    public abstract void invoke();
}
```

Then replace the guts of your function above with this:

```
@Override
public void inform(String data) {
    Command.valueOf(data).invoke();
}
```

The names of your 'enum' values must exactly match the string values of the various things you are testing for in your original code (e.g. C.SubscriptionEvents.WINDOW_CLOSED,  C.SubscriptionEvents.WINDOW_CLOSED)

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify it this way...

```
@Override
public void inform(String data) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, int>();
    map.put(C.Controller.Commands.SELECT_MODE_VERTICES, Mode.VERTICES);
    map.put(C.Controller.Commands.SELECT_MODE_LINES), Mode.LINES);
    map.put(C.Controller.Commands.SELECT_MODE_SECTORS, Mode.SECTORS);
    if (data.equals(C.SubscriptionEvents.WINDOW_CLOSED)) {
        File tempFolder = new File("temp");
        File[] files = tempFolder.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File f : files) f.delete();
        }
    } else if (map.containsKey(data)) {
        MainModel.setCurrentMode(map.get(key));
        display.getInfoSection().repaint();
    } 
}
```