# spring beans map with command pattern

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have got `ProductHandler` class with different implementations like for example, `ABCProductHandler`, `DEFProductHandler`, etc.. which are being invoked from a `ProductServiceImpl` class using a command pattern as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049094/replacing-if-else-statement-with-pattern).

**ProductServiceImpl class:**

```
@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    private Map<ProductType,ProductHandler> productHandlersMap = 
                                         new EnumMap<>(ProductType.class);

    private ABCProductHandler abcProductHandler;

    private DEFProductHandler defProductHandler;

    //....10 other product handlers goes here

    @Autowired
    public ProductServiceImpl(ABCProductHandler abcProductHandler, 
                                  DEFProductHandler defProductHandler, .....) {
        this.abcProductHandler = abcProductHandler;
        this.defProductHandler = defProductHandler;
        //....10 other product handlers goes here
    }

    @PostConstruct() 
    public void init() {
        productHandlersMap.put(ProductType.ABC, abcProductHandler);
        productHandlersMap.put(ProductType.DEF, defProductHandler);
        //....10 other product handlers goes here
    }

    @Override
    public ProductDetails calculateProductPrice(ProductType productType) {
        productHandlersMap.get(productType).calculate();
        //..some otehr code goes here
        return productDetails;
    }
}
```

However, I am not happy with the above `ProductServiceImpl` class as there are lots of `productHandlersMap.put` calls with boilerplate code.

Now, my question is that is there any way that I can load the `productHandlersMap` easily?

```
@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    private Map<ProductType,ProductHandler> productHandlersMap = 
                        new EnumMap<>(ProductType.class);

    @PostConstruct() 
    public void init() {
         //How to laod productHandlersMap easily with 
         // different ProductHandler types here?
    }

    @Override
    public ProductDetails calculateProductPrice(ProductType productType) {
        productHandlersMap.get(productType).calculate();
        //..some other code goes here
        return productDetails;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring can autowire different implementations of a bean that implements an interface `I` to a property of type `Map<String, I>` automatically, where the key is the *name of the bean* and the value the bean instance. As you already have an enum to target each `ProductHandler` implementation, you could take advantage of it:

```
public enum ProductType {
    ABC(ProductType.ABC_BEAN_NAME),
    DEF(ProductType.DEF_BEAN_NAME);

    public static final String ABC_BEAN_NAME = "abcProductHandler";
    public static final String DEF_BEAN_NAME = "defProductHandler";

    private String beanName;

    ProductType(String beanName) { this.beanName = beanName; }

    public String beanName() { return beanName; }
}
```

Then, define your different `ProductHandler` implementations either in a `@Configuration` factory class or by means of the `@Service` or `@Component` annotation:

```
@Service(ProductType.ABC_BEAN_NAME)
public class ABCProductHandler implements ProductHandler {

    // ...
}

@Service(ProductType.DEF_BEAN_NAME)
public class DEFProductHandler implements ProductHandler {

    // ...
}
```

Now, in your `ProductServiceImpl` bean, simply autowire a `Map<String, ProductHandler>`:

```
@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    private final Map<String, ProductHandler> productHandlersMap;

    @Autowired
    public ProductServiceImpl(Map<String, ProductHandler> productHandlersMap) {
        this.productHandlersMap = productHandlersMap;
    }

    @Override
    public ProductDetails calculateProductPrice(ProductType productType) {
        productHandlersMap.get(productType.beanName()).calculate();
        //..some otehr code goes here
        return productDetails;
    }
}
```

This way, you'd let Spring do all the injection work, and there's no need to even use a `@PostConstruct` method.

Note the use of `productType.beanName()` inside the `calculateProductPrice` method. This ensures you use the correct bean to calculate the price.

Comment: why even maintain a map as spring bean factory maintains this implicitly. All we can do is just invoke context.getBean("bean name") to get the instance. thoughts?

Comment: @siva Because, if you use `context.getBean(...)`, you'd be using Spring code inside your business logic classes. This is discouraged and is also considered bad practice. A map is just a map, from `String` to your beans, that contain more business logic. And sometimes all you need is a map

Answer (score 1):

You can create spring configuration component

```
@Configuration
public class CollectionConfig {

    @Bean
    public ProductHandler  getABC() {
        return new ABCProductHandler(ProductType.ABC);
    }

    @Bean
    public ProductHandler  getDEF() {
        return new DEFProductHandler(ProductType.DEF);
    }

    @Bean
    public ProductHandler  getXYZ() {
        return new XYZProductHandler(ProductType.XYZ);

    }
 

    // other factory methods

}
```

And after that:

```
    @Service 
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService { 
private Map<ProductType,ProductHandler> productHandlersMap = new EnumMap<>(ProductType.class); 

 @Autowired(required = false)
 private List<ProductHandler> beanList;

 @PostConstruct() 
public void init() { 
    beanList.foreach(b->
    productHandlersMap.put(b.getType(), b))
     }
}
```