# How to avoid multiple if else block so that the code does not smell?

Tags: java, if-statement

There are a lot of *if-else* statements in my code what is the best way that I can avoid so many *if-else* statements. Below is the code snippet. Now again I need to check if WWW-Authenticate header returns value

```
signature_invalid
```

then I need to log and return a different error message and if WWW-Authenticate header returns value

```
token_exppured
```

then I need to log a different error message which will again add 2 more ifs. Can anyone Help me how can I avoid this??

```
    if (e.getRawStatusCode() == NOT_FOUND) {
      logger.log(
          log,
          LogLevel.ERROR,
          MISSING_VALID_ID_ERROR_MSG + " : " + e.toString(),
          viewRequest);
      String errorDetails = createNotFoundDetails(appl, transactionId);
      updateIdentifier(rcvLog, true, request, identifier);
      return createErrorViewResponseReply(MISSING_VALID_ID_ERROR_MSG, errorDetails);       

 } else if (e.getRawStatusCode() == UNAUTHORIZED) {
      logger.log(
          log, 
          LogLevel.ERROR,
          UNABLE_TO_REACH_ERROR_MSG + " : " + e.toString(),
          viewRequest);
      if (e.getResponseHeaders() != null && e.getResponseHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE != null)) {
      logger.log(
          log,
          LogLevel.ERROR,
          INVALID_TOKEN_ERROR_MSG + " : " + e.getResponseHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE),
          viewRequest);
      }
      updateIdentifier(rcvLog, false, request, identifier);
      return createErrorViewResponseReply(
          UNABLE_TO_REACH_ERROR_MSG,
          INVALID_TOKEN_ERROR_DETAILS);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing if else statement with pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049094/replacing-if-else-statement-with-pattern)

Comment: you dont need the first else, for a start..an if will do.

Comment: You can use `switch` and also break into multiple methods.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28049596/10416835

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic approaches one can take with this is:

1. Create a class hierarchy with a factory to instantiate the right instance to respond to the action
2. Do the same but in short hand with Enums
3. Use a map of **this::method()** and call your methods that do the work for you

For your case, since you can't really control the types of code an API sends you, and a factory method may be overkill, a map approach may be best:

```
map.put(NOT_FOUND, this::methodA);
map.put(UNAUTHORIZED, this::methodB);
map.put(OTHER, this::methodC);

map.computeIfAbsent(
   e.getRawStatusCode(), 
   (e, rc, req, id) -> {/** NOTHING */}
).apply(e, rcvLog, request, identifier);
```

**computeIfAbsent()** allows you to handle the unhandled case with basically a no-op.

Comment: This is a very clean approach.What if I want to just follow this approach inside unauthroized block and create a map with values returned by WWW-Authenticate header like map.put("signature_invalid", this::methodA); and map.put("token_expired, this::methodB),if I do this then how can I use omputeifabsent to return createErrorViewResponseReply()

Comment: I have not used computeIfAbsent before ,so I am new to this new map method

Comment: computeIfAbsent() is totally optional you can also do:

var method = map.get(e.getRawStatusCode());
if (null != method)  method.apply(e, rcvLog, request, identifier);

its up to you.

Comment: could you please help me out achieve this map.put(“signature_invalid”, this::methodA);
map.put(“token_expired”, this::methodB);
map.put(“OTHER”, this::methodC);

map.computeIfAbsent(
   e.getResponseHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE), 

).apply();

Comment: I really found this useful in using computeIfAbsent and return createErrorViewResponse reply on different error msgs send by WWW-Authenticate header.So would be really grateful if you can just help me on thta

Comment: maybe like this:
return map.computeIfAbsent( ...).apply(...);
??
you just do a return in the methods and in the lambda