# Best way to replace multiple IF statements with design pattern or cleaner code?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a function that returns an object whose name is Rule. Its structure is below:

```
public class Rule 
{
    public bool ShouldLogInADatabase {get;set;}
    public bool ShouldLogInBDatabase {get;set;}
    public bool ShouldShowNotification {get;set;}
    public bool ShouldSendEmail {get;set;}
}
```

For example, I have this code:

`var rule = ExecuteRule();` //This method returns Rule object.

Now, I have to run some functions based on rule like:

```
if(rule.ShouldLogInADatbase==true)
{
//Run some code
}

if(rule.ShouldLogInBDatabase==true)
{
//Run some code
}

if(rule.ShouldShowNotification == true)
{
//Run some code
}
```

I need to check each rule object and it is expected in the future more bools can come. I want to write in cleaner way or use some design pattern. How I can do it?

Comment: if all those conditions can occur _independent_ from each other, that seems clear enough to me. don't overcomplicate things by trying to oversimplify things. (jus make sure that `some code` is separated into a method)

Comment: I agree with Franz Gleichmann. The only (very minor) improvements I can think of is making rule class immutable and removing the `== true` inside the if statements.

Comment: I am also thinking to make it simple but just wondering if any design pattern can fit into this

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28049596/4926697

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in using Design pattern, *Chain of Responsibility* is a good option for this

> Chain of Responsibility is behavioral design pattern that allows passing request along the chain of potential handlers until one of them handles request.
> The pattern allows multiple objects to handle the request without coupling sender class to the concrete classes of the receivers. The chain can be composed dynamically at runtime with any handler that follows a standard handler interface.

https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility/csharp/example