# how can I make an int rank based on cards into an Array that will return string values?

Tags: java

I'm trying to clean up code so a selection of values pertaining to a deck of cards rank is an array, I was able to accomplish this with suits, though I can not seem to accomplish it with rank. I simply want to type this out in a way where it will return the same values but not take up so many lines, preferably through an array or linked list.

```java
  public String toString() {
    return getVal() + getSuit();
  }

  public String getVal() {
    int rank = value % 13;

    if (rank == 0) return "2"; else if (rank == 1) return "3"; else if (
      rank == 2
    ) return "4"; else if (rank == 3) return "5"; else if (
      rank == 4
    ) return "6"; else if (rank == 5) return "7"; else if (
      rank == 6
    ) return "8"; else if (rank == 7) return "9"; else if (
      rank == 8
    ) return "10"; else if (rank == 9) return "J"; else if (
      rank == 10
    ) return "Q"; else if (rank == 11) return "K"; else return "A";
  }

  public String getSuit() {
    if (suit.toLowerCase().contains("spade")) {
      return "\u2660";
    } else if (suit.toLowerCase().contains("club")) {
      return "\u2663";
    } else if (suit.toLowerCase().contains("heart")) {
      return "\u2665";
    } else if (suit.toLowerCase().contains("diamond")) {
      return "\u2666";
    }

    return "";
  }
```

Comment: `return new String[]{"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"}[value % 13];`

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049094/replacing-if-else-statement-with-pattern) for multiple methods.

Comment: There are much nicer solutions but a switch expression would already reduce the repetition quite a lot: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html `return switch (rank) { case 0 -> "2"; case 1 -> "3";  ... }`

Answer (score 1):

For the rank, you can set your string values in a `List` with [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E...)) and use `rank` as an index into the list.

```
private static final List<String> ranks = List.of(
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A");
```

Then in the `getVal` method:

```
return ranks.get(rank);
```

For the suit, you need to map a `String` to another `String`, using [`Map.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V,K,V,K,V,K,V)).

```
private static final Map<String, String> suits = Map.of(
    "spade", "\u2660", "club", "\u2663", "heart", "\u2665", "diamond", "\u2666");
```

Then in the `getSuit` method:

```
return suits.getOrDefault(suit.toLowerCase(), "");
```

The [`getOrDefault` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault(java.lang.Object,V)) returns an alternative value in case the mapping doesn't exist, which appears to be what your code is doing after your if-else if block.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can do:

```
if (rank < 9) {
  return String.valueOf(rank + 2);
}
// handle rest individually
```